# How to subtract data value using latest and earliest date (value is in another column) using R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr

I am struggling to understand how I can subtract the blood pressure data if the patient had anywhere from 1 measurement to 5 measurements. For example, my data

| ID | Date1 | Value1 | Date2 | Value2 | Date3 | Value3 | Date4 | Value4 | Date5 | Value5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | 160 | 01/02/2022 | 161 | 01/04/2022 | 159 | 01/05/2022 | 159 | 01/06/2022 | 130 |
| 2 | 08/02/2022 | 130 | 01/07/2022 | 120 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 3 | 01/04/2022 | 112 | 29/09/2022 | 161 | 10/10/2022 | 159 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 4 | 01/10/2022 | 182 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |

So some patients will have all 5 measurements (e.g. ID 1) when some patients will have only 1 measurement (e.g. ID 4).

I want to make a new variable that subtracts from the latest value to the earliest value. If the patient only has 1 measurement, the new variable will be NA. For example like this.

| ID | Date1 | Value1 | Date2 | Value2 | Date3 | Value3 | Date4 | Value4 | Date5 | Value5 | NewVariable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | 160 | 01/02/2022 | 161 | 01/04/2022 | 159 | 01/05/2022 | 159 | 01/06/2022 | 130 | -30 |
| 2 | 08/02/2022 | 130 | 01/07/2022 | 120 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | -10 |
| 3 | 01/04/2022 | 112 | 29/09/2022 | 161 | 10/10/2022 | 159 | NA | NA | NA | NA | 47 |
| 4 | 01/10/2022 | 182 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |

I am using R Studio for this. I would appreciate any coding help to achieve this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the first value is always located in Value1 and that the dates are sorted correctly, the `dplyr` package makes it straight-forward.

Use `coalesce` to find the first non-missing value 2-5 (in reverse order), and substract value 1 from that.

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, NewVariable = coalesce(Value5, Value4, Value3, Value2) - Value1)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 12
#>      ID Date1      Value1 Date2      Value2 Date3      Value3 Date4      Value4 Date5      Value5 NewVariable
#>   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1     1 01/01/2022    160 01/02/2022    161 01/04/2022    159 01/05/2022    159 01/06/2022    130         -30
#> 2     2 08/02/2022    130 01/07/2022    120 <NA>           NA <NA>           NA <NA>           NA         -10
#> 3     3 01/04/2022    112 29/09/2022    161 10/10/2022    159 <NA>           NA <NA>           NA          47
#> 4     4 01/10/2022    182 <NA>           NA <NA>           NA <NA>           NA <NA>           NA          NA
```